# Fetch int (11) date from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

What I'm trying to do is to fetch date and time from `int(11)` from mysql and display it in PHP:

```
<?php

$dbusername     = 'dbuser';
$dbpassword     = 'dbpassword';
$dbhost     = 'localhost';
$dbname     = 'dbname';


        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
        if (!$conn)
        {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }


        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
        if (!$conn)
        {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);


        $query = "SELECT from_unixtime(mycolumn) FROM mytable";

?>
```

but the page loads and nothing shows up.

What's wrong?

Comment: 1. [Execute your query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) 2. [fetch your query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) 3. [display results](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jeffrey said is right

but do not recommend call mysql function, you can try like this:

```
$query = "SELECT from_unixtime(mycolumn) as timestamp FROM mytable";
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo date('Y-m-d', $result['timestamp']);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but it keeps on giving me the same output although i deleted the row.... and does this show all the values in the column or only the first row value?

Comment: Yes first value, return all column use this SQL "SELECT * FROM mytable", maybe you should learn mysql_* function in php document

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing your query:

```
$query = "SELECT from_unixtime(mycolumn) FROM mytable";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["field1"];
        echo $row["field2"];
        echo $row["field3"];
        // ...
    }
}
```

*On a side note: notice the red box in the PHP manual in every `mysql_*` function:*

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have stopped at building the query..

I guess you will have to add this to see some output..

```
   $result=mysql_query($query);

    $num=mysql_numrows($result);

    mysql_close();

    echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b><br><br>";

    $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) {

    $field1-name=mysql_result($result,$i,"mycolumn");
    echo "<b>$field1-name";

    $i++;
    }
```